# Auto sizing UITextField inside UITableViewCell Follow Cursor

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, swift4

I have a fullscreen `UITableView` with a header view which contains some text (about 300px tall)

I have a single `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UITextField` that expands in size as you type.

I'm looking for a possible solution to make the `UITableView` scroll to the position of the cursor in the `UITextField`

Some examples of this working in iOS are notes app and mail app.. Any help is appreciated. Is this possible?

Comment: Just add an UITextView and disable scrolling, then use auto table height, it will do what you need

Comment: `UITextField` height will not increase better to use `UITextView`.

Comment: I have uitextview i mean